# xml data to excel conversion

Tags: c#, xml, excel, type-conversion

How would I convert the following data to excel. The input data is in `.txt` files and looks like this:

```
<xml>1,4,,5,<header>2,44,,55,6,2,</header></xml>
<xml><header>23,5,6,,2</header>3,4,5,66,,</xml>

and so on..
```

Basically strip the tags and put the data into excel. Each number should be in its own cell, blank values should result in blank cells. For the above example, the output in the `.xls` should look something like this..

```
1 4   5  2 44  55 6 2  
23 5 6  2 3 4 5 66
```

Can't really do any formatting to make the output look better but basically each number in its own cell and a blank where there's data missing. By data missing, I mean nothing between two commas in the input as you can see above (`,,`).

Also before people ask me what I have tried, I was converting the data to csv and then using EPPlus to write it into an excel file but there were too many issues with that, it was not a direct conversion and the data was not being correctly written and my code was just too messy. So not a good idea to troubleshoot and fix that. I'm sure there's a simpler solution. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: it seems like if you could simply strip all of the tags the data would already be in a csv format, which excel can handle

Comment: Just as a workaround, you can try to replace doble comma (',,') by single comma (',') in the csv file.

Comment: for example you could replace all "<.*>" with "" in most editors

Comment: @Freerider i think he wants the double comma right? the csv would interpret that as a blank cell

Comment: @pasquers Ok, I'm sorry! I misunderstood!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XSLT, the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the following input:

```
<input>
   <row>1,4,,5,<header>2,44,,55,6,2,</header></row>
   <row><header>23,5,6,,2</header>3,4,5,66,,</row>
</input>
```

produces the following CSV:

```
1,4,,5,2,44,,55,6,2,
23,5,6,,23,4,5,66,,
```

You can easily add some column headings as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the final steps after I actually took the time to run through the example:

1) Load the file in any text editor

2) find a way to run a find of "<.*>" and replace with ""

3) save the file with a .csv extension

4) on next opening try opening with excel

-those steps produced what you wanted for me

Comment: I tried doing that, however in some cases, some data elements are very long in which case they span 2-3 cells. I want each number in 1 cell. That's one issue I noticed. Secondly, if the input has something like, 12:30, Excel displays it as #####

Comment: hmmm. We must be using different versions of excel. Inputting a long number just got rounded off for me, and 12:30 was converted to 12:30:00.... What version of excel are you using?

Comment: possible, I'm using Excel 2010